# How can I get the types in Dictionary<int, string>?

Tags: c#

The requirement is like this. Now I have a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int,string> dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();
//... some other operations
Type t = typeof(Dictionary<int,string>);
```

Now I want to get the type int and string. How can I get the two? Thank you very much.

Update:

Thank you for the response. Actually my requirement is to create another generic class based on the two types, which were got from the dictionary type. Just like this.

```
PropertyType propertyType = typeof(Dictionary<int,string>);
if (propertyType.Name.Contains("Dictionary"))
{
    Type keyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type valueType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[1];
    propertyType = typeof(SerializableDictionary<keyType, valueType>);
}
//And after this, it will dynamically create a class and add the propery as one
//of its properties
```

Now I cannot use `propertyType = typeof(SerializableDictionary<keyType, valueType>)`. How should I update this statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a snippet:

```
Type keyType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type valueType = t.GetGenericArguments()[1];
```

Update:

```
var typeOfNewDictonary = typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>)
                               .MakeGenericType(new[] 
                                           { 
                                               keyType, 
                                               valueType 
                                           });
```

BTW:
The following line is wrong:

```
PropertyType propertyType = typeof(Dictionary<int,string>);
```

It should be rather:

```
Type propertyType = typeof(Dictionary<int,string>);
```

What's more, condition in `if (propertyType.Name.Contains("Dictionary"))` has no sense. It always be evaluated as `true`.